# store session data to a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database-connection, session-state

Can i store session value in a table with button click. In my code below I want the `UserName` in table..

Here is the code I'm using:

```
string cmdstr = "select count(*) from Reg where UserName='" + TextBoxaun.Text + "'";
SqlCommand checkUser = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);

int temp = Convert.ToInt32(checkUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
if (temp == 1)
{
    string cmdstr2 = "select Password from Reg where UserName='" +   TextBoxaun.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand pass = new SqlCommand(cmdstr2, con);
    string password = pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    con.Close();

    if  (password == TextBoxapass.Text)
        Session["newapply"] = TextBoxaun.Text;
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code has sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: what you want to do ? store to session data from the content of table ? or store session data to table ?

Comment: store session data to a table@Shyju

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need [ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

After you create ASPState database, you must change session state mode in web.config like this:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" 
              sqlConnectionString="[Database connection string]"/>
```

P.S. When you are using SQLServer or StateServer modes, objects must be serializable. For more details see [Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)